# How do I extract the body out of the MongoDB Document from my get request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I am trying to access the `Question` field in the body of a JSON document inside a MongoDB. When I run the GET request I get something that looks like this:

```
{
"_readableState": {
    "objectMode": true,
    "highWaterMark": 0,
    "buffer": {
        "head": null,
        "tail": null,
        "length": 0
    },
    "length": 0,
    "pipes": null,
    "pipesCount": 0,
    "flowing": null,
    "ended": false,
    "endEmitted": false,
    "reading": false,
    "sync": true,
    "needReadable": false,
    "emittedReadable": false,
    "readableListening": false,
    "resumeScheduled": false,
    "destroyed": false,
    "defaultEncoding": "utf8",
    "awaitDrain": 0,
    "readingMore": false,
    "decoder": null,
    "encoding": null
},
"readable": true,
"domain": null,
"_events": {},
"_eventsCount": 0,
"_opts": {},
"_destroyed": false
}
```

I was reading about JSON body parsers but adding that does not seem to be working. Here is my `index.js`:

```
 var express = require('express')
 var mongojs = require('mongojs')
 var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
 var app = express()
 var db = require('./myDB.js')

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
 app.use(bodyParser.json());

 app.use(express.json())
 app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Hello'))

 app.get('/getFlashCard', (req, res) => {
 let flashID = req.body._id;
 db.getFlashCard("Interview Questions", flashID, function(docs) {
    console.log("Flashcard retrieved: ", docs);
        res.send(docs);
    });
 });
```

Here is my `myDB.js`:

```
getFlashCard : function(colName, flashID, callback) {
    let data = mongodb.collection("Interview Questions").find({
        "_id" : flashID
    });
    callback(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

here you are returning the promise model instead of the actual resolved data.

```js
getFlashCard : async function(colName, flashID, callback) {
 const data = await mongodb.collection("Interview Questions").find({_id : flashID });

   callback(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Notice that you are not waiting for the `find` to finish, instead you are assigning `data` to `mongodb.collection("").find`

You need to wait for `find` to finish by either using a callback (check out https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/api-generated/collection.html#find) or by using async/await.